# Check if value of referenced row matches value in current row

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

See the following database structure:

```
                        v---------------------------------------------------|
  v----------------------------|---------------------------|                |
+---------------+    +----+---------+------+    +----+---------+---------+-----+
| id | username |    | id | user_id | tag  |    | id | user_id | message | tag |
+----+----------+    +----+---------+------+    +----+---------+---------+-----+
| 1  | User1    |    | 1  | 1       | tech |    | 1  | 1       | Test1   | 1   |
| 2  | User2    |    | 2  | 1       | news |    | 2  | 2       | Test2   | 1   |
+----+----------+    +----+---------+------+    +----+---------+---------+-----+
   users                    tags                       messages
```

`tags.user_id` and `messages.user_id` both reference `users.id`. `messages.tag` references `tags.id`.

Users have tags available (rows in `tags` where `rows.user_id = users.id`) and messages (rows in `messages` where `messages.user_id = users.id`).

The problem is that *any* tag can be "attached" to the message, instead of only tags that are owned by the user. So I need an extra restriction that ensures that the tag referenced in `messages.tag` not only exists (foreign key restriction), but is also owned by the same user as the message itself (`messages.user_id = tags.user_id`).

I have not found a way yet to achieve this restriction, which is why I'm asking help.

- python: `3.8.10`
- `sqlite3.version`: `2.6.0`
- `sqlite3.sqlite_version`: `3.31.1`

Comment: You can declare (user_id,tag) UNIQUE in tags and use it in your FK

Comment: @Serg I partially understand what you're saying. I understand the UNIQUE restriction in `tags`. However, what do you mean with using that restriction as my FK? Do you mean a foreign key "connection" like this: `messages.tag -> (tags.id, tags.user_id)`? What SQL command would I need to use to create such restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual creating a composite FK in Sqlite3 looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE parent(a PRIMARY KEY, c, d, e, f);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i1 ON parent(c, d);

CREATE TABLE child3(j, k, FOREIGN KEY(j, k) REFERENCES parent(c, d));
```